# How to store my app-generated photos in subfolders / subalbums

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, photos

I am creating a sample app to exercise with the FB Graph API using Javascript.

What I want to do is, let the user add a text entry on a diary, and attach an image. I'd store the text entry on my server, and post the image (or multiple images) on the default app photo album.

But, I don't want all my app pictures to be grouped together, I'd like to categorize them.

I.e. I want to post entries about my garden, and an album for every tree / flower I have.
Do you know if (and if so, how) can I create a sub-album inside by app album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such 'sub album' functionality, but there's no reason your app can't create different albums via the regular API and use those for the uploads

Comment: Ok, so instead of using the default application album, which has no current limit on the # of photos I can post into, I should use regular albums, limited to 200 photos each. Maybe when an album is filled up I can move the old photos to the default application album, or just avoid complexity and create a new album with the month name, like "Geraniums January 2012. I just wonder what would be best and less invasive for a user that may add lots of photos (say 10 per day).